# How to find execution time of classification algorithms in R?

Tags: r, execution-time

I am running a naive bayes classifcation algorithm in R. I want to calculate the execution time of the algorithm.
Shall i use

```
Start_time <- proc.time()
{                
  #execution of naive bayes classifier
}
End_time <- proc_time()
Exec_time = End_time - Start_time
```

to find the execution time.
Is it the right way to calculate the execution time of an algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You can use package **microbenchmark** or **rbenchmark** to test code.

First define a function:

```
myfunction <- function(){}
```

then define how many times should run the function

```
n <- 10
```

Here is an example using **microbenchmark**:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myfunction(),times=n) #run your function "n" times
```

Here is an example using **rbenchmark**:

```
rbenchmark::benchmark(myfunction(),replications=n) #run your function "n" times
```

For both packages you can get the result using operator `<-`. For example:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(a<-myfunction(),times=n) # result is in variable "a"
rbenchmark::rbenchmark(a<-myfunction(),times=n) # result is in variable "a"
```